# Wordpress displays 10 post type items

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-post-type

I used the **Custom Post Type UI** Wordpress plugins to create a **custom post type** (Venues) and a **custom taxonomy** (Venue Type). I then created around 65 Venue items and tried to display them on the page using the following loop script. Unfortunately results are only limited to 10 Venue items per Venue type. Any ideas why?

```
        <?php 

          $args = array(
              'orderby' => 'name',
              'hide_empty' => true,
              'taxonomy' => 'venue_type'
          );
          $categories = get_categories($args);

          foreach( $categories as $category ) {
            echo '<div class="ui-accordion-header">';
              echo "<div>";
                echo "<h3>" . $category->name . "</h3>";
                echo "<p>" . $category->description . "</p>";
              echo "</div>";
            echo "</div>";
            $newargs = array(
             'post_type' => 'venue',
             'tax_query' => array(
              array(
               'taxonomy' => 'venue_type',
               'field' => 'slug',
               'terms' => $category->slug
              )
             )
            );

            echo '<div>';
              echo "<div>";
                echo '<ul class="cs-grid cs-style">';
                  query_posts( $newargs );
                  if (have_posts()) :
                      while (have_posts()) : the_post();
                        echo "<li>";
                          echo "<figure>";
                            the_post_thumbnail();  
                            echo "<figcaption>";    
                              echo "<h3>"; 
                                the_title(); 
                              echo "</h3>";
                              echo "<span>"; 
                                the_field('location');
                                echo " "; echo "|"; echo " ";
                                echo 'Capacity'; echo " "; the_field('capacity');
                              echo "</span>";
                            echo "</figcaption>";
                          echo "</figure>";  
                        echo "</li>";
                      endwhile;
                  endif;
                echo "</ul>";
              echo "</div>";
            echo "</div>";

          }

       ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the 'Settings -> Read' page in the Wordpress admin pages. There you can configure how many posts should be displayed per list page.

This blog post can also be useful: http://weblogs.about.com/od/wordpresstutorialstips/tp/How-To-Configure-Wordpress-Reading-Settings-For-Your-Blog.htm

Best of luck!

/Wille

Comment: In the scope of things, your answer's alright, but it would be better to include a canonical example from the link above, if that link were to ever go dark.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I am rather new to writing answers at Stackoverflow. Will keep this in mind for future! :)

Answer (score 0):

This is probably happening because you have it set to only display 10 items a page. Adding `'posts_per_page' => -1,` should work.

```
$newargs = array(
         'post_type' => 'venue',
         'tax_query' => array(
          array(
           'taxonomy' => 'venue_type',
           'field' => 'slug',
           'terms' => $category->slug
          )
```

would become

```
$newargs = array(
         'post_type' => 'venue',
         'tax_query' => array(
          array(
           'taxonomy' => 'venue_type',
           'field' => 'slug',
           'terms' => $category->slug,
            'posts_per_page' => -1
           )
```